# How to make a very simple coloured 1-line text area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a regex editor in Electron, and I want to make a regex input box at the top. I've looked at the way Atom does it - by having lots of divs stacked on top each other, which contain spans for the coloured parts.

I've done this, so far:

```
<body onload="load()">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="regex-input">
        <div class="line" id="line">
          <span class="red">Hello</span>
          <span class="black">, world</span>
          <span class="orange">!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I also have a load of CSS which is way too big to put into the question, which makes it look like this:

[image: Example]

Any tips on how to do this? I've been searching all over the internet for a way to do it but I can't find anything.

Here's an image of the kind of thing I want: (from http://regexr.com)

[image: Regexr]

Comment: External links tends to die and as such they are useless for future users, so put code within the question. I find it difficult to understand what you mean so an _image_ showing the expected outcome would be good.

Comment: Okay - I didn't think it would be a good idea to put the code into the question as there's so much of it. I want something similar to http://regexr.com, I'll put an image in the question.

Comment: If there's too much code to go into the question then you have to reduce that to the minimum amount required to reproduce your problem (see the "*[mcve]*" guidelines); in this case I think it's probably a moot point since, effectively, this is a request for an off-site resource, tutorial, library... which is explicitly off-topic for this site, because the answer has the potential decay so very rapidly and cannot be objectively/correctly answered.

Comment: I don't think it's a request for an off-site resource - I'm just asking for tips on how to do the thing. Anyway, I'll try to put some code into the question

Comment: regexr.com seems to use codemirror

Comment: The question's title says "a very simple", but the thing you are trying to achieve is not simple. There are several ways to do it, you will evetually have a stack of tags to color the bits.

Comment: Yeah, I realise now - I thought it'd definitely be simpler than it actually is xD

Comment: You have two separate problems. One is to parse the regexp. That will require a regexp parser--I'm sure you can find one somewhere. The second is to generate the appropriate-colored HTML for each piece, which you seem to already have a good handle on how to approach. So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already good tools to do this, you don't have to write your own. CodeMirror is a very popular tool, look at [this](http://codemirror.net/1/contrib/regex/).

If you want to write your own, one way is to not use an input element, use spans to represent each token, and have a blinking div to represent a cursor. Capture the keyboard keys and navigate that blinking div accordingly, and remove, color, and add spans as the user types new tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I saw codemirror before but it didn't look like the kind of thing I was looking for, but that link looks interesting - I'll try and use that

Comment: I'd try to use something existing, it's not trivial writing your own little syntax highlighter with JS. :)